# How can I get the length of dependently typed interval?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

Say I have a data type

```
data Interval :: Nat -> Nat -> * where
  Go :: Interval m n -> Interval m (S n)
  Empty :: SNat n -> Interval n n
```

These are half-(right-)open intervals. `Nat` are the standard inductive naturals, `SNat` are the corresponding singletons.

Now I'd like to get a singleton `Nat` for the length of a given interval:

```
intervalLength :: Interval n (Plus len n) -> SNat len
intervalLength Empty = Z
intervalLength (Go i) = S (intervalLength i)
```

This does not work, as the `Plus` function is not injective. I could probably define it like

```
intervalLength :: Interval m n -> SNat (Minus n m)
```

but that would require some lemmas (and additional constraints), I guess. Also, my intervals arise in the former shape.

Background: I tried to do this in Omega and it did not work ([omega bug I filed](https://code.google.com/p/omega/issues/detail?id=109))

Also how could these problems be cracked with modified typecheckers? Can the RHS of the supply the crucial hint to LHS pattern's type equation so that the non-injectiveness cancels out?

How do Agda programmers tackle these problems?

Answer (score 13):

Here's my version of your program. I'm using

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}
```

and I've got `Nat` and its singleton

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data SNat :: Nat -> * where
  ZZ :: SNat Z
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat (S n)
```

Your `Interval` type is more familiar to me as the "suffix" definition of "less-than-or-equal": "suffix" because if you upgraded from numbers to lists and labelled each `S` with an element, you'd have the definition of a list suffix.

```
data Le :: Nat -> Nat -> * where
  Len :: SNat n -> Le n n
  Les :: Le m n -> Le m (S n)
```

Here's addition.

```
type family Plus (x :: Nat) (y :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance Plus Z     y  = y
type instance Plus (S x) y  = S (Plus x y)
```

Now, your puzzle is to count the `Les` constructors in some `Le`-value, extracting the singleton for the difference between its indices. Rather than *assuming* that we're working with some `Le n (Plus m n)` and trying to compute a `SNat m`, I'm going to write a function which computes the difference between *arbitrary* `Le m o`-indices and *establishes* the connection with `Plus`.

Here's the additive definition of `Le`, with singletons supplied.

```
data AddOn :: Nat -> Nat -> * where
  AddOn :: SNat n -> SNat m -> AddOn n (Plus m n)
```

We can easily establish that `Le` implies `AddOn`. Pattern matching on some `AddOn n o` reveals `o` to be `Plus m n` for some `m` and hands us the singletons we wanted.

```
leAddOn :: Le m o -> AddOn m o
leAddOn (Len n) = AddOn n ZZ
leAddOn (Les p) = case leAddOn p of AddOn n m -> AddOn n (SS m)
```

More generally, I'd advise formulating dependently typed programming problems minimizing the presence of defined functions in the indices of types over which you plan to match. This avoids complicated unification. (Epigram used to colour such functions green, hence the advice **"Don't touch the green slime!"**.) `Le n o`, it turns out (for that is the point of `leAddOn`), is no less informative a type than `Le n (Plus m n)`, but it is rather easier to match on.

Yet more generally, it is quite a normal experience to set up a dependent datatype which captures the logic of your problem but is absolutely ghastly to work with. This does not mean that all datatypes which capture the correct logic will be absolutely ghastly to work with, just that you need think harder about the ergonomics of your definition. Getting these definitions neat is not a skill that very many people pick up in their ordinary Functional Programming learning experience, so expect to climb a new learning curve.

Answer (score 8):

I had a go at this in Idris. While I agree with pigworker's suggestion of reformulating the problem, here's what you'd have to do to get your definition past the Idris type checker. First, the singleton Nats:

```
data SNat : Nat -> Set where
   ZZ : SNat O
   SS : SNat k -> SNat (S k)
```

Then, the definition of intervals:

```
data Interval : Nat -> Nat -> Set where
  Go : Interval m n -> Interval m (S n)
  Empty : SNat n -> Interval n n
```

The definition you want for intervalLength looks a bit like this:

```
intervalLength : Interval n (plus len n) -> SNat len
intervalLength (Empty sn) = ZZ
intervalLength (Go i)     = SS (intervalLength i)
```

But you'll run into trouble, because as you say `plus` is not injective. We can get somewhere by additionally pattern matching on `len` explicitly - then unification can make some progress:

```
intervalLength : Interval n (plus len n) -> SNat len
intervalLength {len = O}   (Empty sn) = ZZ
intervalLength {len = S k} (Go i)     = SS (intervalLength i)
```

This is fine, and gets past the typechecker, but unfortunately it doesn't believe that the function is total:

```
*interval> :total intervalLength
not total as there are missing cases
```

The missing case is this one:

```
intervalLength {len = O}   (Go i)     = ?missing
```

If you try this, and ask the REPL for the type of `missing`, you'll see:

```
missing : (n : Nat) -> (i : Interval (S n) n) -> SNat O
```

Now, we know that the type `Interval (S n) n` is empty, but alas, the type checker does not. Somehow we need to write `badInterval : Interval (S n) n -> _|_`, then we can say:

```
intervalLength {len = O}   (Go i)     = FalseElim (badInterval i)
```

I will leave the definition of `badInterval` as an exercise :-). It's not especially tricky, but it is a bit boring to have to do - sometimes it's hard to avoid having to work with types of this sort, but implementing `badInterval` backs up pigworker's suggestion of not doing it this way!

Comment: There is, of course, the question of why one would bother defining the singleton Nats in Idris. And of course, you've got `len` already! The problem as originally formulated is really quite peculiar when rendered in a full-spectrum dependently typed language.